# Visual Studio Environment Best Practices?

Tags: visual-studio, vmware

I have a VM on my Win 7 machine running Server 2008.  My website can't run properly unless it's running on the server due to COM+, other website integration and environment variables.  Currently, I have VS2008 installed on the Windows Server 2008 and I develop there (which is dumb, I know) instead on in my Win 7 workstation.  I hate this setup.

My question is, how can I developer on my workstation and then EASILY push and test th websites on the VM Server?

Access files across the network so the actual changes are made on the VM Server?

Make changes locally and publish to VM Server?

Can I set up VS2008 so that if I when I Run the application in VS2008 it pushes everything over and opens a web browser that points to the VMServer's IIS Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the VM *is* a server on your network. Exactly like any other server on your network, virtual or otherwise.

For debugging you can setup VS2008 to remote debug but I think you'd have to publish the site, start it and then hook up the debugging but I'm happy to learn that there's an easier way... anyone?

Comment: SharePoint works in the same way and it's recommended to develop on the server. The only alternative is remote debugging which is painful. @EdenMachine: Why do you hate the setup?

Comment: It's just a pain to develop in a VM when all my other apps are in my workstation.  I would like to run the VM in the background.